# How to check sim lock via Terminal Emulator

Tags: terminal

I wonder, is it possible to check sim lock status in Terminal Emulator? Is there any universal command for most of Android phones?

I know many different ways to check this issue, but I'm just curious.
Thanks

Comment: Well, I don't think that there's any trick available that can help you in checking the SIM lock with the help of Terminal Emulator. I would say maybe we can wait a bit more while over this, so if any other member over here has any idea about it!